# CSS: relative vs absolute positioning for a fixed sized page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am developing web applications for SmartTV devices, which have a fixed size. Its either 720x1280 or 1080x1920. With this in mind, what is better to use, relative or absolute positioning? I have gone through other similar questions, but they do not favour absolute positioning because it is inflexible. I do not need flexibility, so will I benefit from using absolute positioning?

Comment: Sorry, that was relative vs absolute.

Comment: Your question still does not make any sense, and even if it did it probably would not be a good Stackoverflow question. If you were to post your actual markup and an example of the positioning problem you have, then that would be much clearer.

Comment: You need to take a step back and properly learn CSS layout methodologies. You probably don't need to use positioning at all.

Comment: I can place the same element by either relative or absolute positioning, will I get a better performance by using one over the other?

Answer (score 1):

If you're absolutely certain this design will never need to be applied to a different-sized viewport, then knock yourself out: go ahead and use all the absolute positioning you want.   I wouldn't say you'd necessarily "benefit" from using it -- it's rarely necessary to depend on absolute positioning if you structure your html and css reasonably; and since you already have two viewport sizes to support you won't be able to just slap a fixed position on every element and call it a day -- but it won't hurt anything.

That is... until the day when you inevitably *do* need to change the design to suit a different device, at which point you'll probably have to start from scratch because you'll have baked in too many dependencies on the original screen size(s).

(That said, either you're using the wrong terminology, or you have some confusion about "relative" vs "absolute" positioning.   The CSS `position:relative` rule is mostly useful for controlling the layout of absolute-positioned child elements; they wind up positioned relative to the element which has `position:relative`, instead of relative to the document.   So you're not making a choice between "absolute or relative positioning", it's a choice between absolute positioning (which will likely also involve some `position:relative`), or a responsive layout.)